# Destructuring undefined inside an object vs array

Tags: javascript

Following code gives empty object `{}`:

```
{ 2, {...undefined}}
```

But why does below code gives error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable`?

```
{ 2, [...undefined]}
```

Comment: Indeed that is true. What is your question?

Comment: Assuming you are using keys in both of your objects (or you meant to use `[]` instead of `{}` as your outermost brackets), otherwise, you'll get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number" with both examples

Comment: @NickParsons `{ 2, {...undefined} }` works in chrome's console. It probaby considers `{}` as a block and returns the result of the the comma operator.

Comment: @adiga ah good point, that's most likely how OP is running the above code

Answer (score -2):

You cannot destructure an array if it's not an array for sure.
It's ok to have an empty array so the given value will be undefined.

You can use this to prevent access undefined OR non-iterable value:

```
const a = undefined
console.log(...(a ?? []))
```